# Does skewness decrease standard deviation ceteris paribus?

Tags: distributions, variance, standard-deviation, skewness, moments

For a given probability distribution, probability mass must sum to 1, thus by increasing a parameter corresponding to skewness do you shift probability away from the second central moment (variance) to the tails, thereby reducing standard deviation in general?

Comment: It might be useful to know which distribution you're considering.

Comment: 1. If you're shifting probability "to the tails" you'll generally be increasing variance. 2. It's not clear to me how you intend to hold other things equal (apart from variance and skewness, apparently), since to change skewness you have to change *something* about the distribution, and that necessarily changes some other things. 3. Leaving that aside, it is possible for variance to be constant while changing skewness.

Comment: To muddy the waters a little, skewness is a vague concept that can be measured in several different ways. Thus for example (mean $-$ median) / SD is a simple but sometimes useful measure, and furthermore it is easy to find distributions with mean $=$ median that you wouldn't want to call skew.

Comment: @NickCox Mean = Median or Mean $\ne$ Median?

Comment: @Dave What I wrote. Consider 0 0 1 1 1 1 3 where mean $=$ median and the skewness measure is thus 0 but the example is clearly not symmetrical. Many binomial distributions are skew but have mean and median equal.

Comment: Because variance can be considered independently of any property of a distribution's shape (its square root is usually used to establish a *scale* for the distribution), *no* change in shape (of which skewness, however defined, is one indicator) is necessarily associated with changes in variance.  BTW, variance is not particularly special in this regard: for instance, you could use any $L^p$ norm (such as the fourth root of the kurtosis) to establish a scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NO**

Let's develop a counterexample. We will use a $\text{Beta}(1, \beta)$ distribution where $\beta$ controls the skewness and variance.

[Equations for variance and skewness of a Beta distribution are taken from the Wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution)

```
beta_var <- function(a, b){

    return(
        (a*b)
        /
        ((a+b)^2*(a+b+1))
    )
}

beta_skew <- function(a, b){

    return(
        (2*(b - a) * sqrt(a + b + 1))
        /
        ((a + b + 2) * sqrt(a*b))
    )
}

a <- 1
b <- 1
beta_var(a, b) # 0.0833333333333333
beta_skew(a, b) # 0

a <- 1
b <- 2
beta_var(a, b) # 0.0555555555555556
beta_skew(a, b) # 0.565685424949238

a <- 1
b <- 1/2
beta_var(a, b) # 0.0888888888888889
beta_skew(a, b) # -0.63887656499994, magnitude 0.63887656499994
```

Moving from $\text{Beta}(1, 1)$ to $\text{Beta}(1, 2)$ makes the distribution more skewed while decreasing the variance. Moving from $\text{Beta}(1, 1)$ to $\text{Beta}(1, 1/2)$ makes the distribution more skewed (in the other direction) while increasing the variance.

Therefore, adjusting the skewness can both increase and decrease the standard deviation.

Comment: If you see a mistake in the skewness and variance equations or a bug in my code, please let me know, as the counterexample relies on those being correct.